# SLDS Responsive Classes (setting gutter size for different breakpoints)

Tags: css, slds, slds-grid, responsive-design

Apologies if I missed it in the documentation, but I'm wondering if the Salesforce design system provides any way to change the gutter amount based on breakpoints?

Via classes, I see you can change the column size of something based on breakpoints (`.slds-medium-size_1-of-3` for example).  Is the same possible for gutters (or margin/padding/any other slds class utility value) or is that only available for a column size?

Comment: There are variable gutter sizes, but it does not appear that they can be tied to breakpoints unless you write your own stylesheets: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#Column-Gutters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know those breakpoints are also available to control the visibility with slds-hide or slds-show, but I'm afraid there aren't that many more classes supporting this.

You could use these classes and create a version for each that would suit the slds-gutter of your preference, but there must be a better approach to this.

Comment: Thanks -- forgot about hide/show.  I was hoping there would be more, but it's sounding like having to create new/custom classes in a global stylesheet is the only way to achieve this at the moment.